# How do nested default control elements work?

Tags: javascript, html, w3c

I'm trying to fugure out, how does browser interract with default behaviour of nested controls.

Well I have the following code:

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">
    <span><input type="checkbox">Hello</span>
</a>
```

Well if I clicking on the `<input>` tag, I got the changed status, but I don't get following to the link (why? and in the same time, I'll see changing text highlight from the all of the `<a>` wrapping). But if I click on the text `"Hello"` I'll following to the link?

How does it work? I need explanation by whatwg spec.

Comment: `a` and `input` are both considered interactive elements, and as such are _not allowed_ to be nested in HTML.

Comment: @CBroe but if I do, what will happen?

Comment: Why? This is either a XY Problem or something worse.

Comment: Whatever the browser vendor decided to actually implement for this situation. _"I need explanation by whatwg spec"_ - this structure is against the specification, so don't expect the resulting _behavior_ to be specified either.

Comment: @CBroe could you specify your words in spec? I mean where in spec says about these restrictions on nested default controls

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element "Content model:
    Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant, a element descendant, or descendant with the tabindex attribute specified."

Comment: And fwiw, this case is actually an interop issue. Firefox will follow the link, Chrome won't. I think I saw an issue about this so that this interop issue is fixed but I don't remember where. (because, yes, even when things are forbidden, there is supposed to be an unique behavior across all UAs).

Comment: @Kaiido it's interesting. But there doesn't say what implementors should do if content model were violited. What should do implementors in that case?

Comment: It might just not be specified. Specs don't work like a "rule" that's written and everyone had to follow it blindly, they're the reflection of what the implementers did. When there is an interop issue like here, it needs to be discussed which is deemed the best behavior and which vendor(s) has to change their implementation. As I said I think I remember I saw that discussion begin somewhere but I don't remember where, but anyway, this is just a corner case that is probably not worth the time of anyone. As an author it is your duty to not write code that enters this path.

Comment: @Kaiido Do I correctly understand that there is no place in spec where nested default elements could be explained how they should interop?

Comment: That depends on the elements, but for the one case you exposed here, no, the specs don't seem to treat it, yet. (I didn't search thoroughly though)

Answer (score 0):

[Section 13.2.6.4.7](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody) of the HTML Standard on parsing HTML has a section

> A start tag whose tag name is "a"

which explains the process for the similar 'nested `<a>`' case:

> If the list of active formatting elements contains an a element between the end of the list and the last marker on the list (or the start of the list if there is no marker on the list), then this is a parse error; run the adoption agency algorithm for the token, then remove that element from the list of active formatting elements and the stack of open elements if the adoption agency algorithm didn't already remove it (it might not have if the element is not in table scope).

Comment: This is yet another case, here the parser will move the nested <a> outside of its parent. But you can still have that DOM tree through JS, so handling it at parsing alone isn't enough anyway.